# Slack misses tray indicator

Tags: indicator, gnome-shell, system-tray, slack

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04, I installed Slack but it doesn't show any icon in the tray indicator:

```
▶ snap info slack       
name:      slack
summary:   Team communication for the 21st century.
publisher: slack
contact:   https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us
license:   unknown
description: |
  Caution: Slack for Linux is in beta. We’re still busy adding features and
  ironing out potential issues.

  Slack brings team communication and collaboration into one place so you can
  get more work done, whether you belong to a large enterprise or a small
  business. Check off your to-do list and move your projects forward by bringing
  the right people, conversations, tools, and information you need together.
  Slack is available on any device, so you can find and access your team and
  your work, whether you’re at your desk or on the go.

  Scientifically proven (or at least rumored) to make your working life simpler,
  more pleasant, and more productive. We hope you’ll give Slack a try.

  Stop by and learn more at: https://slack.com/
commands:
  - slack
snap-id:   JUJH91Ved74jd4ZgJCpzMBtYbPOzTlsD
tracking:  stable
refreshed: 2018-03-31T00:45:51+02:00
installed:   3.1.1 (6) 98MB classic
channels:              
  stable:    3.1.1 (6) 98MB classic
  candidate: ↑              
  beta:      ↑              
  edge:      3.1.1 (6) 98MB classic
```

Comment: In my case it's not only slack, tray icons aren't working at all. I think this is the same as: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030833/app-indicator-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Nope, in my case it's only Slack. Telegram, nextcloud, KeePass, jetbrains toolbox, all of them work

Comment: True, tried telegram and it works. Did you install slack from snap or downloaded from slack.com?

Comment: Problem persists both with the snap and .deb version downloaded from slack.com. Both v3.1.1.

Comment: Having the same problem. I didn't see this on the deb but I have to use the snap because slack causes conflicts that will remove virtualbox from my system

Answer (score 13):

I was able to fix the issue by installing appindicator extention

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with all tray icons in Ubuntu 18.04.

What worked for me was disabling *Ubuntu appindicators* extension using  *gnome-tweak-tool*. I then ran `sudo apt purge indicator-common` in a shell, re-enabled Ubuntu appindicators and rebooted my PC.

All the tray icons were back!