# Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome desktop does not have tray icon for qz-tray - why?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, indicator, system-tray

I'm using `qz-tray` application installed/downloaded [from GitHub: qzind/tray](https://github.com/qzind/tray/releases/download/v2.0.7/qz-tray-2.0.7.run).

It does not show tray icon in Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome desktop.
What should I do to show it?

Comment: Do you have `gnome-shell-extension-appindicator` package installed? What is the output of `apt policy gnome-shell-extension-appindicator`? Are you in a "vanilla" GNOME session by any chance?

Comment: May be related https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030833/app-indicator-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04 . What application you use? For example `hplip-gui` and `psensor` show their icons on clean installation of standard 18.04 LTS. But `guake` does not show its icon.

Comment: @N0rbert I'm using qz-tray

Comment: @xybrek where can I download `qz-tray`? Does it exist in ubuntu repositories?

Comment: @N0rbert here https://github.com/qzind/tray/releases/download/v2.0.7/qz-tray-2.0.7.run

Answer (score 1):

I ran the following commands to install QZ Tray (based on [official guide](https://github.com/qzind/tray/wiki/install-dependencies#ubuntu)):

```
sudo apt-get install git ant nsis makeself default-jre
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://github.com/qzind/tray/releases/download/v2.0.7/qz-tray-2.0.7.run
chmod +x qz-tray-2.0.7.run
sudo ./qz-tray-2.0.7.run
```

- At first I tested it in normal traditional desktop - Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS and it has tray icon in place here just after installation:

  [image: qz-tray MATE]
- Then I switched to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with GNOME:

  1. With default settings it is not shown (i.e. `gnome-shell-extension-appindicator` is installed, enabled and loaded).
  2. Then installed *TopIcons Plus* extension from GNOME Software - it shows icon in non-expected place (note green printer near Firefox icon and black square near clock):

  [image: QZ Tray with TopIcons Plus]

  1. Afterwards I removed *TopIcons Plus* and installed *TopIcons* extension - it does not work even if I start it manually with `java -Xms512m -jar "/opt/qz-tray/qz-tray.jar"`.

So I recommend to drop this brave new GNOME world and switch to fully functional traditional [MATE desktop environment](http://mate-desktop.org/) by executing `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop^`.
As normal users we do not have time to overcome all these new non-predicted difficulties.
Also you can try to find support on GitHub [issue page to fix this problem](https://github.com/qzind/tray/issues/60) for GNOME.

Answer (score 0):

Starting [with 2.0.9](https://github.com/qzind/tray/issues/60#issuecomment-460916694), QZ Tray detects the absence of a System Tray and attached to the Taskbar icon instead.

Here's QZ Tray running on ElementaryOS:

[image]

Solutions including the System Tray compat libs (or avoiding Gnome entirely) are the correct solution for those using older QZ Tray versions, however those looking to use a newer version of QZ Tray no longer need to make special considerations.  It should work out of the box.