# Useless/broken options on Ubuntu Tweaks? (Ubuntu 19.04)

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-tweak-tool

On the Ubuntu Tweaks application, there are two Extensions that I have no idea what they do. When I enable them, nothing seems to happen on my screen. Anyone knows how to use them or if they even work?

[image]

Comment: You may find this helpful - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030833/app-indicators-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04 , or https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1301/ubuntu-appindicators/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @guiverc, as he already provided the links about the uses of those extensions..

These gnome-shell-extensions are pre Installed with the Ubuntu.ISO and configured in the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/modes/ubuntu.json`

```
{
    "parentMode": "user",
    "stylesheetName": "Yaru/gnome-shell.css",
    "debugFlags": ["backtrace-crashes-all"],
    "enabledExtensions": ["ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com", "ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com", "desktop-icons@csoriano"]
}
```

This causes, the toggle button useless.. from the `gnome-tweaks` extensions tab..

you can remove these extensions from the line `"enabledEstensions":`

```
{
    "parentMode": "user",
    "stylesheetName": "Yaru/gnome-shell.css",
    "debugFlags": ["backtrace-crashes-all"],
    "enabledExtensions": []
}
```

now all the 3 pre enabledExtensions will respect the toggle button..

[image]

Note: this concept of `modes`, `ubuntu.json` will apply to ubuntu desktop session which is default in Ubuntu 19.04

[image]

If you install different desktop sessions and logged into that session, this case varies based on that sessions configuration..